# Write a PHP code to print following number pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns, printing, numbers

```
Write a PHP code to print following number pattern:
147
258
369
```

I am trying like this but its shows me shows below. how to convert column to row pattern.

```
<?php
    $num = "";
    for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++) {

        $num .= $i; 
        if($i%3==0){
            $num .="<br />";
        } 

    }
    echo $num;
?>
```

```
please help me
```

Comment: hi @user1309690 upper part of question you can see the pattern to print value like shows. i want like this

Comment: hey @Pie thank you so much for your suggestion. i will do that thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use for loop inside for loop to achieve this. Below is the code

```
$num = "";
for( $i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++ ) {
    for( $j = 0; $j <= 2; $j++) {
        $k = $i + ( $j * 3 );
        $num .= $k; 
    }
    $num .= "<br />"; 
}
echo $num;
```

Comment: i am getting the same and and i want like to show my question. i want result like upper pattern.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. It prints the same like your upper pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get this output.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
   $print = $i;
   for($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++) {                
       echo $print;
       $print = $print + 3;
   }
   echo "<br />";
}
```